# gnuplot: subtitle with smaller fontsize

Tags: gnuplot

Does somebody know how you can insert a subtitle with a smaller fontsize in gnuplot?

Currently, the way I create a subtitle is by using `\n` in the title.  Additionally, I would like the subtitle to have a smaller fontsize.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26):

This works for the postscript terminal at least (for some reason `x11` didn't want to scale my font.  Perhaps it is a bug...):

```
set term <whatever> enhanced
set output "<whatever.ext>"
set title "Big Title\n{/*0.5 subtitle}"
```

The `{/*0.5}` scales the fontsize to be half of the current active fontsize.  You can also specify fontsizes explicitly:

```
set title "{/=20 Big} Medium {/=5 Small}"
```

---

Or you can change the font for a region of text:

```
set title "{/Helvetica foo} {/Symbol G}"
```

These forms can be combined to change the font and size in a particular region of text as well:

```
set title "This is a big gamma {/Symbol=20 G}"
```

For more information about enhanced text, see `help enhanced`.

Comment: Thank you! It works great, I tried it with output to PDF on windows 7 and that works perfectly.

Comment: I wanted to print a graph for each day for 8 years with month-view and yearview and hat about 80-120 pages, when this solution crashed because of "Cairo is unhapp: out of memory" --> not using enhandced color solved it, but now I need a different format

Answer (score 4):

You can use `label`. You have to experiment a bit with its proper placement by `at`:

```
set title "Big Title"
set label "Subtitle" at screen 0.5, 0.9 font "Arial,8"
plot sin(x)
```