# How can I increase the font size of the ylabel in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I tried to do `set yabel={/*2.0 MyLabel}` based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643583/gnuplot-subtitle-with-smaller-fontsize), but that just printed the ylabel with those literals.

Answer (score 17):

You can specify the font options simply by using the `font` argument like so:

```
set xlabel "x-units" font "Times-Roman,12"
set ylabel "y-units" font "Times-Roman,12"
```

Or you can just leave out either parameter, say for example if you want to set the font size but not the font face:

```
set xlabel "x-units" font ",12"
set ylabel "y-units" font ",12"
```

The official gnuplot documentation [can be found here](http://gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf), and I'd also recommend checking out http://www.gnuplotting.org/

Comment: This looks much cleaner than the `"{/*2 Ylabel}"` stuff.

Answer (score 10):

The terminal must have the `enhanced` option enabled, and your syntax for setting labels is wrong (without `=`). A working example:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced
set xlabel "Xlabel"
set ylabel "{/*2 Ylabel}"
set output 'fontsizetest.png'
plot x
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This solution does not work in the context of www.burningcutlery.com/derek/bargraph/ when I am trying to output to pdf. I tried to add "enhanced" to the set terminal line in his script, but this resulted in syntax error for gnuplot.

Comment: @merlin2011 The `bargraph.pl` script uses the `fig` terminal which does not support enhanced text (I don't know why).